# How to cast string with AM/PM to timestamp in pandas

Tags: pandas, type-conversion, timestamp

I have such row `29-08-17 11.34.58.548518 PM,` how to convert it to timestamp in pandas:

Such approach didnt work

```
pd.to_datetime('29-08-17 11.34.58.548518 PM', '%d-%m-%Y %H.%M.%S', dayfirst = True)
```

Comment: Did I missing something , or you just change the post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop `dayfirst`, because that information is included in your formatting string. To include your entire datestring, including `.548518 PM`, use the `%f` and `%p` directives:

```
pd.to_datetime('29-08-17 11.34.58.548518 PM', format='%d-%m-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
```

Returning:

```
Timestamp('2017-08-29 23:34:58.548518')
```

`%f` stands for Microsecond as a decimal number, and `%p` stands for Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for more)

Comment: `29-08-17 11.34.58.548518 PM` converted to `2017-08-29 11:34:58.548518`. But we have PM  so result should be  `2017-08-29 23:34:58.548518`

Comment: You're right, you should use `%I` instead of `%H` (edited)

Answer (score 0):

In addition getting rid of PM/AM is not an option: we have to handle everything right. Final solution:

`pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime('29-08-17 11.34.58.548518 PM', format='%d-%m-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p'), format='%d-%m-%y %H.%M.%S')`